# Stothers-Mason theorem

Tags: polynomials

Let $f$, $g$ be coprime polynomials of degree $n$. The Stothers-Mason theorem tells us that $fg(f+g)$ has at least $n+1$ roots.

**Question**

- Is there a  description of the cases of equality?
- Specifically, is it true that in case of equality we have $\operatorname{deg}(f+g)<n$? This seems to
  be the case for $n$ up to $4$.

Answer (score 4):

Look up Belyi maps. See, for instance, the third page of Granville and Tucker’s survey paper on the $abc$ conjecture: [It's as easy as $abc$](https://www.ams.org/notices/200210/fea-granville.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, Silverman's proof as outlined there easily provides a positive answer to my question. More generally, one could ask what are the possible values of